# Can someone explain about script variable "environment"?

Tags: g1ant

what is environment variable and how does it work?

♥image = ♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\image.png

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation of environment variables on the G1ANT Website: [Environment Variables](https://manual.g1ant.com/appendices/environment.md)

Basically what `♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧` is doing is specifying a path to C:\Users\YOURUSERNAMEHERE (The drive letter could be different, it is C:\ on my computer)
So `♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\image.png` would be something like `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAMEHERE\Desktop\image.png`